# Skype audio device batch file

Tags: windows, batch, skype, input-device

I need to create a `.bat` that will change my Skype mic input to a virtual audio cable and the speakers output to a different virtual audio cable, and it cannot affect the Windows default devices in any way.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Thought: can this be done with Powershell, or does it need to be limited to batch? Usually Powershell can accomplish a whole lot more. You might want to start with checking the registry to see if these settings are there. The registry is manipulable with batch (mostly through executing saved registry files).